# React-Native Firebase Auth : [auth/unknown] A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred

Tags: firebase-authentication, react-native, react-native-firebase

My Application is in production and the verification works well, but I have a problem with the verification of phone numbers on phones Samsung and other with run Android 5.X , 7.0.

The exeution of this code:

```
firebase
         .auth ()
         .verifyPhoneNumber (phoneFullNumber)
```

generate the error: `[auth/unknown] A network error (such as timeout, interrupted connection or unreachable host) has occurred`

My Package :

```
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^6.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^6.3.4",
"react-native": "0.61.5"
```

Thanks

Comment: I have same issue in Android 9